# Admob ads v11.6.0 with targetSdk=25 produce TimeoutException

Tags: android, admob

When I use targetSdk=25, this error is written to logcat:

```
Error waiting for future.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ac.get(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:51)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:182)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.x.call(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.y.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951036:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.k.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    ... 3 more
```

With `targetSdk`=26 no error is written to Logcat.
Is it ok to use Admob v11.6.0 if `targetSdk`=25?

Comment: im getting the same on target = 20 same sdk version

Comment: @markharrop Did you solve this problem too? It did not crash apps but it's showing.

Comment: no mate i didnt